# 12.04 Upgrade: Sound Input Issues

Tags: upgrade, sound, noise

I don't know how to follow [these instructions](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Upgrade0.html).

What do I have to write exactly in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is for Debian systems and of limited use for Ubuntu. In Ubuntu you need these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install alsa-hda-dkms
sudo reboot
```

*And this:*

> Sound was much better. Now has a level of contstant white noise in the
>   background. On advice I also added the following to
>   /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, but made little difference to the
>   background noise - so stay with it for now - sounds okay.

*means this:*

Edit the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Finally, add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus
```